# Function is not defined while exist

Tags: webpack

I'm using a function `(ShowPopUpProject)` in `home.html` that defined in `javascript.js`.

> its never mind what my function is .
>   I just add it in my `webpack.config.js` :

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports =
    {
        mode: 'production',
        entry: [

            './js/javascript.js',
            './js/javascript2.js',

        ],
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
            filename: "bundle.js"
        }

    };
```

I used **`ShowPopUpProject`** in other functions at `javascript2.js` ,
when i run `run npm build` or `webpack` i got error in my bundle.js file :

> **`ReferenceError: ShowPopUpProject is not defined`**
>
> As you see i defined the function in `javascript.js` and when use in
>   `javascript2.js` and build the `webpack` file receive this error. how can
>   i fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webpack entries are the root of your dependency tree, so what you are telling Webpack is:

- Create a file called bundle.js with ./js/javascript.js and all its dependencies (requires/imports)
- Create a file called bundle.js with ./js/javascript2.js and all its dependencis (requires/imports)

If javascript2.js never imports javascript.js then it will not know about the function in javascript.js because it is a separate dependency tree.

If you're really are trying to make two bundles, then use something like `[name].js` in output, and use import/require in the files to make sure the functions are defined where they are needed.

Comment: What exactly i need  is root of my dependency tree without using import/require what i want to do is simple just move my all `js` file to `bundle.js` and minimize it.

Comment: what is your suggest ?

Comment: If you want to concatenate the contents of all your js files into bundle.js and minimize it I believe you have to use import or require. Webpack works by building a dependency tree on each entry. So you'd need a main.js or index.js where you specify require('./javascript.js') and require('./javascript2.js'). And then only have main.js as your entry in webpack.